# How to cut off Steam from the internet in windows?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, blocking, steam

I want to disable internet connection for Steam in Windows 7. How can I do this? (Steam offline mode is not an option for me)

After change firewall rules, Steam is automatically adding his own firewall rule, for private and public connections. With both, allowing and blocking rule on the list, firewall is allowing Steam to connect.

Is there any other way to block internet connection for application in Windows?

I dont want to install any other firewalls. It would be great to enable and disable this connection via command line.

Comment: If you block Steam then you will be unable to play your games, offline mode works, for a very specific reason with the Steam DRM.

Comment: Most of my games works completely fine without internet connection, so it's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Windows `hosts` file to redirect any requests to the Steam service to your local machine (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`). Those requests will be going straight into the void and Steam will not have any way to work around this issue, except for changing the servers they connect to (which you can block then, as well).

You can find out which servers to block using Wireshark, or you can just google and try to find a list of Steam service IPs.

[This](http://steamdomains.blogspot.de/) list may be useful.